# SSE/SIMD instructions on arrays: dealing with boundaries

Tags: arrays, filtering, sse, simd, convolution

I have a question related to to Intel SSE instructions but it is general of SIMD programming/parallelism.

For instance, we can consider a [1D filter/convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163423/pipelining-1d-convolution-algorithm-using-c-on-dsp-development-board). If the size of the kernel is 3, I have to avoid the first and last elements of the input array as they do not have a neighbour (yes, I have to set a boundary condition). It is easy to treat that 'special cases' separately of the rest of the elements of the input array (check the code in the link above to see the different 'if' statements).

When employing SSE with 8-bit data, for instance, I can compute 16 values at a time (128-bit/8-bit=16 simultaneous operations). However, how should I manage the boundary condition? In this case, I have the problem with the last 16 values (15, actually), even if the array size is multiple of 16.

I am not sure if I am explaining the problem correctly. The point is: How should I hanble the boundaries when dealing with arrays and SIMD instructions? I search for related source code, but I do not found anything wich explain this point, even on Intel's website. Any idea will be welcome.

Comment: You handle them the same way you would do manual loop-unrolling. Insert cleanup code before and/or after the main loop.

Comment: The amount of if-statements for code cleanup drops the performance too much, I do not found a real benefit using SSE compared to conventional programming. I can't found the right way to handle this.

Comment: If that's the case, then either you're not doing it right, or the trip count for the loops is too small to be worth optimizing at all.